# Renovate bot not adding reviewers for BitBucket

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-cloud, renovate

We are using Renovate to keep our dependencies up to date. Our code is hosted in BitBucket cloud. I have added a reviewers configuration to the renovate.json but it doesn't add any reviewers to the PRs that it creates.

For the reviewers I have tried using: email address, BitBucket username, BitBucket user ID. None of these works. Example subset of renovate.json is below.

```
 "enabledManagers": ["npm", "nuget"],
   "reviewers": [
    "bb_username"
  ],
```

The logs don't mention anything about reviewers.

Does this functionality work with BitBucket and if so, how should it be configured.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is pretty straightforward: use the UUIDs of the users instead, with `{}` surrounding them:

```json
{
  "reviewers": [
    "{6ce7dd2c-0824-4df9-920d-4017a9f35da8}",
    "{b08e11a1-4cbf-4b3c-98c9-5470e663bec8}"
  ]
```

The tricky part is to get the UUIDs of the users.

For that, you have to call an endpoint that gives you the UUIDs, e.g.:

```bash
curl -X GET -u 'user:password' 'https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/workspaces/{workspace}/members' | jq '.values[].user | "\(.display_name) \(.uuid)"'
```

I really hope this works for a longer time because the BitBucket API seems to be changing and the documentation is basically useless.

Some references:

- https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate/issues/14716
- https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Adding-reviewers-to-pull-requests-via-REST-API/qaq-p/710084 (especially see [this recent](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Adding-reviewers-to-pull-requests-via-REST-API/qaq-p/710084#M96801) comment which contradicts a bit what the renovate bot does)